# Warning "name.xml" is not a supported asset file

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

i made model.xml file in my project. and try to call it using data modal

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    content: ListView {
        dataModel: XmlDataModel {
            source: "model.xml"
        }
        listItemComponents: [
            ListItemComponent {
                type: "item"
                PhotoListItem {

                }

            }
        ]

    }

}
```

but here at line " source: "model.xml" " it is giving me warning model.xml is not a supported asset file. 
i want to know why it is so because model.xml contains images path and due to warning images are not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file "model.xml" is in your asset folder in the project, as I expect it to be, you should refer to it with asset:///model.xml

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
Page {
  content: ListView {
    dataModel: XmlDataModel {
      source: "asset:///model.xml"
    }
    listItemComponents: [
      ListItemComponent {
        type: "item"
        PhotoListItem {}
      }
    ]}
}
```

Comment: Actually that is not necessary

Comment: Actually, it depends where the actual file is located. Since 10.0 beta 3 there were changes to relative paths for `QmlDocument`. `QmlDocument` now loads the files from the current working directory (previously from the assets directory). To obtain the former behavior, you need to use `asset:///` scheme. More info could be found here https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/upgrading/upgradingtobeta3.html